# Wildcard query % fetches wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the tables from my database where they start with **srt_factor_** (which in this case are only the first two).

My tables are:

```
srt_factor_20121119
srt_factor_20130430
srt_factorxyzk_20130813
```

My query erroneously returns instead of the first two tables only, the last one as well (srt_factorxyzk_20130813)

```
Select (TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'srt_factor_%';
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'_'` is a wildcard in SQL Server, representing one character.  Try this instead:

```
Select (TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND 
      TABLE_NAME LIKE 'srt[_]factor[_]%';
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the underscores which have a special meaning in SQL (it's like the `*` wildcard, but for exact one character). You have to escape them like this:

```
TABLE_NAME LIKE 'srt[_]factor[_]%'
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.110).aspx) on the use of wildcard characters as literals.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the underscore in brackets.

```
LIKE 'srt_factor[_]%';
```

Underscore is used to match any single character.